# "fatal: bad tree object" error when pull from remote branch

Tags: reactjs, git

When I pulled changes form remote-branch it shows this error.
Even if I removed .git/gc.log .still exits this error "Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.".

Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
warning: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
and remove .git/gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

fatal: bad tree object ea60c4a29147cef831a8aa3f71313c64281b8078
fatal: failed to run repack

Already up to date.
```

Comment: Corrupted Git repos are never fun. There may be better ways to go, but faced with this I would probably create a fresh clone and copy my changes into it. Do you have any local commits and changes you want to keep in this sandbox?

Comment: No, it is updated on my working branch. but when I pulled changes from  develop branch it corrupted git repos.

Comment: Then I would just try again in a fresh clone and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Yes @joanis, now I am going to try again fresh clone. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should put some effort into figuring out how and why the repository got corrupted in the first place (e.g., is your storage subsystem failing, or did you put the repository in a cloud-synced folder? either of these might do it).